# npm run test: Error: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mocha.js

`npm run dev` and the server connects to MongoDB just fine. Output below:

[image]

However, `npm run test` and this happens:

[image]

In package.json I have the following:

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha test",
    "dev": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  }
```

Can someone explain the error? It seems like the test command requires a separate connection to the db or it's not giving mongoose enough time to connect.

Full content of the test file:

```
const chai = require("chai");
const chaiHttp = require("chai-http");
const app = require("../app.js");

chai.should();
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe("/POST ping", () => {
  it("it should return 200 and message", (done) => {
    chai
      .request(app)
      .post(`/ping/`)
      .send({ message: "hello" })
      .end((err, res) => {
        res.should.have.status(200);
        res.body.should.have
          .property("response")
          .eql("Server is running. Message received: hello");
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: What are the contents of the test that is throwing this error?

Comment: In this case the test contents are irrelevant. I commented out the entire test and it still threw the same error. Inside the test file the error can be traced to 
`
const app = require("../app.js")
`
The db connection is working when running the dev server. Stopping the server before running the test has no effect.

Comment: The error indicates that the connection string passed to mongoose is `undefined`. How do you set the connection string?